# change the dataframe like each row only contain one value rest is 0

Tags: python, pandas

[image: DAtafarame]

I have a dataframe like this how can I change the dataframe like each row only contain one value rest is 0.
for eg, in first row 1,3 , 0 , 0 , 0 second row 0,25,0, 0 and so on randmonly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it in numpy, given that the dataframe you start with is called `df`.

```py
import numpy as np

# create an array of zeros shaped like the dataframe
zs = np.zeros_like(df)

# pick which column from the dataframe should be copied, per row
idx = np.random.randint(zs.shape[1], size=zs.shape[0])

# This line has the majority of the magic. I'm using smart indexing from numpy
# to extract the selected columns and assign them to the array filled with zeros,
# using the same smart indexing trick to place them in the correct positions in 
# the resulting array
zs[range(zs.shape[0]), idx] = np.array(df)[range(zs.shape[0]), idx]

print(zs)

# to get a dataframe, you can use
df_copy = pd.DataFrame(zs, columns=df.columns)
```

Comment: IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 1

Comment: well, it worked on my machine. Can you share the dataframe that you're using, please? Without that, it's hard to reproduce the error and help you